# Is it possible to query the ViewPoint property of Graphics3D?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

After showing some graphics objects with Graphics3D you can move the image by interactively changing the ViewPoint option, or by simply dragging, resizing or rotating the image. Does the latter change the ViewPoint internally? Can this be queried?

For example.

By program:

```
 Manipulate [
 viewpoint->{x,y,y};
 Graphics3D[Cuboid[],ViewPoint->viewpoint],
 ,{x,-25,25}
 ,{y,-25,25}
 ,{z,-25,25}]
```

By 'mouse'

```
Graphics3D[
    Cuboid[]]
```

Effects of by program above can be simulated. Can I 'query' effect on ViewPoint as a result of i.e. the rotation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this code:

```
gr = Graphics3D[Cuboid[], SphericalRegion -> True, Boxed -> False]

(* this is one way to extract the values: *)
vp = ViewPoint /. AbsoluteOptions[gr]
vv = ViewVertical /. AbsoluteOptions[gr]

(* the following is completely another way. try rotating the output of this: *)
Row[
 {Show[gr, ViewPoint -> Dynamic[vp], ViewVertical -> Dynamic[vv]],
  Show[gr, ViewPoint -> Dynamic[vp], ViewVertical -> Dynamic[vv]]}
]

(* values will dynamically update here: *)
Dynamic[vp]
Dynamic[vv]
```

Hope this helps come up with a solution to your problem.

**EDIT:**  You can also just copy and paste an already mouse-rotated graphic into `ViewPoint /. Options[...]`

Comment: Cool! I thought it was not possible! I underestimated `Dynamic`. Thank you for pointing this out!

Comment: @Szabolcs. I forgot to ask. Where is this documented? ( If at all. )

Comment: On my system (mma8.01/win7-64) `vp = ViewPoint /. Options[gr]` and
`vv = ViewVertical /. Options[gr]` just output the words `ViewPoint` and `ViewVertical`. `Options[gr]`just gives: 

`Out[28]= {SphericalRegion -> True, Boxed -> False}`

Comment: @Sjoerd, @Szabolcs here too (also v8.0.1)

Comment: @Sjoerd, do exactly as he describes.

Comment: @ndroock1, @Szabolcs it does not work here. I also have trouble understanding why it should work, as if I display `gr` by evaluating the symbol and then rotate the displayed expression using my mouse, `gr` itself doesn't change (so why should `Options[gr]`? and it doesn't here). What am I missing here?

Comment: @acl `gr` does not change, you are right. Only `vp` and `vv` change when rotating 3D inside the output of `Row[...]`. @Szabolcs has given here two very different approaches and the first approach with `vp = ViewPoint /. Options[gr]` is incorrect (`Options` must be replaced with `AbsoluteOptions`) and has no any relation to the second approach with `Dynamic`.

Comment: @ndroock1 I did and it failed. As @Alexey and @acl confirm, the first method is incorrect. The second one starts being pink, indicative of an error. Probably because vp and vv are ill defined at that time. They get defined once you move the cube.

Comment: @Sjoerd This problem can be solved by defining initial values for `vp` and `vv`: `vp = {1.3`, -2.4`, 2.`}; vv = {0.`, 0.`, 1.`};`.

Comment: @Alexey Yep. The error occurs because the two incorrect lines define vp as the _symbol_  ViewPoint and vv as the _symbol_ ViewVertical. I wonder whether mma7  works differently here. Judging from ndroock1's statements it does.

Comment: @Szabolcs I have corrected the code in your answer for preventing further misunderstanding.

Comment: @Alexey, thanks for the correction.  I copied the code from some old notes where I had `Options[Graphics3D]`, just to initialize the values and avoid red boxes. But I changed it here to make it more relevant to the question.  I didn't realize that `Options[gr]` will return an empty list unless the graphics has already been rotated.

Answer (score 4):

Here is enhanced version of the code by Szabolcs. The main difference is that usage of `DynamicModule` allows to avoid pink background of `Graphics3D` which indicates an error due to undefined symbols `vp` and `vv`. This output works right even after saving the notebook and restarting *Mathematica* without re-evaluating the code!

```
gr = Graphics3D[Cuboid[], SphericalRegion -> True, Boxed -> False];
DynamicModule[{vp = ViewPoint /. AbsoluteOptions[gr], 
  vv = ViewVertical /. AbsoluteOptions[gr]}, 
 Column[{Row[
    Table[Show[gr, ViewPoint -> Dynamic@vp, 
      ViewVertical -> Dynamic@vv], {3}]], Dynamic@vp, Dynamic@vv}]]
```

This behavior is [well-documented](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DynamicModule.html): "Values of local variables in a `DynamicModule` are by default automatically saved when a notebook containing the `DynamicModule` is saved, so that these values in effect persist across sessions of *Mathematica*".

Comment: @ndroock1 It works for me. Did you do exactly as he describes?   ;-)

Comment: Yes. It works... but after some serious 'dragging' Mathematica crashed.

Comment: @Sjoerd. I have mma 8.0.0. Maybe that explains it.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done manually by selecting the cell containing your graphics and giving the menu command `Cell > Show Expression` (ctrl-shift-E). The graphics are replaced with the corresponding cell expression and the `ViewPoint` option setting is visible in plain text.

Another possibility is:

```
Cases[ NotebookGet[EvaluationNotebook[]], (ViewPoint -> e_) -> e, Infinity]

(* Out[51]= {{1.73834, -2.29064, 1.78357}, {0.651043, -0.128738, 
  3.31807}, {-3.03116, -1.38541, 0.585417}} *)
```

This finds all occurrences of ViewPoint in your notebook and outputs their coordinates. You'll probably know which one you need.